# Converting Rijndael encryption from python 2 to 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rijndael

I am trying to update some code from python2 to 3 and have some issues with a specific encryption function. This is the python 2 code:

```
trans_raw = '6c9474469ddf7578f3e5ad8a4c703d99'
raw_prime = '583423bbbf900e9a211664861e28c9f347835017'

transkey = trans_raw.decode('hex')
prime = raw_prime.decode('hex')[:16]

r = rijndael.rijndael(transkey)
result = r.encrypt(prime).encode('hex')

print result

#result = fa016bdda2f884d9126fc746f5a00714
```

the rijndael used in this function was from this: https://github.com/sectroyer/SmartCrypto/blob/master/PySmartCrypto/rijndael.py

I have tried converting this to python3 but i dont feel like im coming anywhere close.
This is what i have tried

```
trans_raw = '6c9474469ddf7578f3e5ad8a4c703d99'
raw_prime = '583423bbbf900e9a211664861e28c9f347835017'

transkey = binascii.unhexlify(trans_raw)
prime = binascii.unhexlify(raw_prime)[:16]

r = AES.new(transkey, AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = r.encrypt(prime)
result = binascii.hexlify(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
print(result)

#result = ba5a2b6bb7176dd321250e7d672b0a4a
```

i have tried using https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/1291836#gistcomment-901601
which someone in the comments said was updated for python 3. I have also tried using the built in python AES.new(transkey, AES.MODE_ECB) but neither of those options return anything close to what i am looking for. Does anyone know what i am missing?

Comment: Right, AES is a variant of Rijndael. Presumably the Python 2 setup didn't use the same blocksize.

Comment: i know the block size needs to be 16. in both implementations that should be the default

Comment: Gah, the gist code 'Python 3' version doesn't use bytes, they are basically relying on a string being latin1 encoded. That's.. definitely wrong.

Comment: Note that even with latin1 decoding / encoding, the Python 3 gist code produces `ba5a2b6bb7176dd321250e7d672b0a4a`...

Comment: I'd say that the implementation you found at SmartCrypto is the one that is wrong here, not the AES implementation.

Comment: Ah. Well in either case i need that specific SmartCrypto implementation. i ran it through 2to3 to export it as python3 code but it is still breaking because the lengths of the input are not what it is expecting

Comment: I can confirm that the SmartCrypto implementation must have some kind of alteration or bug in it. Every other Rijndael implementation produces ba5a2b6bb7176dd321250e7d672b0a4a

Comment: i found a reference file and diffed it. the one line that seems to be changed is this one that changes the number of rounds
#num_rounds = {16: {16: 10, 24: 12, 32: 14}, 24: {16: 12, 24: 12, 32: 14}, 32: {16: 14, 24: 14, 32: 14}}
num_rounds = {16: {16: 3}}

Comment: which i can confirm is the only change because changing that one line back causes it to output ba5a2b6bb7176dd321250e7d672b0a4a